# PowerShell: Controlling verbose output in a module

Tags: powershell

So I have this module I will share with a group of people . I want all the output for all the cmdlets IN the module to be have like their where passed -Verbose. Without requiring  the user to actual pass -verbose.  I do not want -verbose output of any other modules cmdlets I call into.

So I tried $Global:VerbosePreference = "Continue" , and then explicitly -verbose:$false for cmdlets I all into.  But it seems the global version overrides the specific version , and I get way to much verbose output.

Is this possible ?

My module is a multi file module , it has over 10 ps1 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'` to the top-level scope of the `*.psm1` script-module file that is referenced in the `RootModule` entry of your module's manifest file (`*.psd1`).

This scopes the preference to the commands in your module, without affecting code outside of it.